# Creating a Queue in Scala

Tags: scala, queue

I am trying to create a Queue in Scala by doing:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Queue

val empty = new Queue[Int]
```

However I am getting an error stating that the Queue constructor is protected. If this is the case, am I missing something? All the Queue methods seem to be defined and working. Must I really extend the Queue class for no reason just to use a Queue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For empty Queue use companion object:

```
val empty = Queue.empty[Int]
```

Comment: Ahh thanks. Hopefully this answer will come up above the articles saying to use `new` in google..

Comment: or `Queue[Int]()`. If the context of the expression (more precisely, the *Expected Type*) makes it clear to the compiler that you're after a collection of `Int`s , you can omit the type parameter, e.g. `val x: Queue[Int] = Queue()`.

Comment: @retronym It is using Queue[Int]() that was not working due to protected constructor. Using Scala 2.9.1.final.

Comment: @providence retronym is saying to use the companion object, val empty = Queue[Int]()

Comment: @Matthew Farwell Oh, sorry. I see that now.

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the factories:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Queue()
scala.collection.immutable.Queue.empty
```

Note that immutable queues are co-variant, so you usually don't need to define a type for it. One exception would be `var` declarations.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val empty = Queue [Int]()
empty: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue()
```